# How to call secured soap web-service

Tags: web-services, soap

I tried to use Web-Services Explorer, SOAPUI, Discover Back-end Service features to form soap envelope for request. Using above features I could  form following  SOAP  request:
 In  Web-Services Explorer

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:q0="http://provider.ws/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
  <q0:callService /> 
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

In SOAPUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:prov="http://provider.ws/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <prov:callService/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Secured Web-Service expect following message. I used TCP/IP Monitor for this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Security xmlns:s="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:w2="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
    <u:Timestamp>
    <u:Created>2015-08-10T13:18:56.644Z</u:Created>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <s:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="w2:LTPAv2" u:Id="ltpa_20">dt8G5gZ9PpZ/Ea5oXr6EQd8dpmfXKiqeXiShPlpSWntK59hUzyoDNX9TKq1nFLfxUEJyJdjMxoG7EVxw8Q1zhyZdYhTXnsMkNVqScvSsPpX7ln/ad+/WAHqaaFymD8XtVEsjOlezQDarPaUmnKAQRUSrLkRnL5B1MoCclTe129Oojg8o+hACgDKjuvPnvL8jaf45wNiou6Il5ZOayBcoHpNehI7i2hADa4fTKzX/T69OPnsZOyWYrNosdezNd24b61vs85k2YK26rLTp5dkEp8f3mwKZBwOOK4z1wQdiAXJf6kQvzR22SfFitbJA5MStlBcovHAvB5T+J5Ip80/kI5BPa2ogoufd9HZAdKTNII8cHpHBN2Ub/+atzg1L7EhIWuzO1BPI62KoU/hPqAHn3uGCGrbIILesKx0TPvlgmU4Bg54H9prC0I8hgXbO1HLuz4M5DNE5ASFbH0W3LJ/UU7BGXJs6iJmfAfJtQ+ip5ZFHlLItZA+ca2LkVWmyD/xKVxyxHE1uDz8zV/CfV9Km0T+8FTA0Cfi/PIb5KiAagdrmqtw6GuJDbSCsC3sdh21G/cA3Y0p/f+rhDw8m/e17y1cEuq9HOBharwn7ET3wO30V4D4rGoLhd4QsN6X1z89gZmZVaI6J9urpPAEiSndmyQ==</s:BinarySecurityToken>
</s:Security>
    <wsa:To>http://X.X.X.X:9082/checkauth/TestServiceService</wsa:To>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:5d1f8656-5550-40d2-9f39-c58f57279489</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action>http://provider.ws/TestServiceDelegate/callServiceRequest</wsa:Action>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:callService xmlns:ns2="http://provider.ws/"/>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is the failure? what is the error?

Comment: @IdanAdar this is log from back-end: The received SOAP request message is rejected becasue it does not correctly specify SOAP action and WS-Addressing action while there is at least one PolicySet attachment at operation level of the TestServiceService.TestServicePort service.

Comment: Why do you think then that it is related to "secure SOAP"? Does it **work** in SOAPUI? Do you get a successful reply?

Comment: @IdanAdar It does not work in SOAPUI. In case when I detach policy set of Web Service,  SOAPUI  return reply when I call that web service. In case when I attach policy set and assign binding to web service in WAS console  service return error in log. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Need I provide more info about this?